# allow_any_instance_of and allow using the instance_double is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara-webkit

Just want to ask if you encounter that when you refactor your spec that before you used the `allow_any_instance_of` then you change it to `allow` it didn't work as what you expect. As we all know in the documentation the `allow_any_instance_of` was already deprecated and they're encourage us to use the `allow`. I still don't know why it didn't work.

Btw, I can't reproduce my code here as this is own by company but the structure is like this.

## Before

```
feature `Something Page Spec here`, retry: 0, js: true do
  # some `let` here

  before do
    sign_in user
    setup_something_here
  end

  describe 'feature here' do
    let( :user ) { create( :user ) }

    before do
      allow_any_instance_of( ActionDispatch::Request ).to receive( :headers ) { { 'something' => 'here' } }
    end

    context 'something here' do
      # then some expectation here
    end

  end
end
```

## After

```
feature `Something Page Spec here`, retry: 0, js: true do
  # some `let` here

  before do
    sign_in user
    setup_something_here
    request = instance_double( ActionDispatch::Request )
    allow( request ).to receive( :headers ) { { 'something' => 'here' } }
  end

  describe 'feature here' do
    let( :user ) { create( :user ) }

    context 'something here' do
      # then some expectation here
    end

  end
end
```

I did pry when I stubbed it in `before` I can get the correct value but then in the `after` it's already nil. I'm confused why it didn't work. Hope there some can help me with this confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here

1. You should not be mocking/doubling in feature tests since it defeats the whole purpose of feature tests (which really makes the rest of these issues moot)
2. `allow_any_instance_of` isn't deprecated, it's use is discouraged because in properly structured tests it shouldn't be needed 99.9% of the time, but it is not deprecated
3. With `instance_double` you create an instance of ActionDispatch::Request - but it's not an instance any other code in your test or app are going to use.
4. It's not clear what exactly your test is checking but, if you're trying to test that headers are set that may be more appropriate for a request spec than feature spec, depending on what headers and what the purpose of them is

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TomWalpole .. I'm wondering if how I can do my feature works well if mocking in feature tests will defeat my purpose. Because in that header request I'm getting the country code from cloudflare which If I did that in test environment cloudflare won't be available and return nil or empty string. How I can able to do that working in feature test without mocking? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @PepengA. Since you're using capybara-webkit you can use `page.driver.header` to set headers that will be sent with requests - see https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#non-standard-driver-methods. Another potential option would be using puffing-billy. If that's not what you're trying to do we'd need more detail on exactly what you're doing to give any more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and it worked well. But one question, what will be the difference with this using the page.driver.header rather than the mocking? I felt like nothing difference as we also set the headers the same in mocking the ActionDispatch::Request.

Comment: @PepengA.  Calling that sets the actual headers the browser sends, and pass through the entire routing, request processing, etc. so you end up doing a full end to end test.  By mocking you are modifying the objects in your system from test code in a way the app never would (not a good idea when you're doing a feature test) and not actually testing that passed in headers get treated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you created just a local variable `request` that lives only inside before block.

If you want this to work you need to also stub controller `request` method to actually return this variable.

Something like this

```
request = instance_double( ActionDispatch::Request )
allow( request ).to receive( :headers ) { { 'something' => 'here' } }
allow_any_instance_of(YourRelatedController).to receive(:request).and_return(request)
```

Comment: hmm .. I don't think you still need to stub the controller as  this `request` is not a instance method of my controller ( it supposed to trigger already the stubbing of request ) , also you're suggesting to use again the `allow_any_instance_of` which I want to eliminate it and last thing I tried to refactor my other feature test and it worked properly with the new method `allow` along with the `instance_double`. Yet I'm still confused what's wrong with this and Thank you @Michał Młoźniak for the answer.

Comment: @PepengA. What I am suggesting is that you cannot create local variable in one block and expect it to exists in another block of code. Just try to inspect request inside your controller and see what kind of object it is. Even better try to inspect request at the beginning of your spec code and you will see that it is nil. Another way to get rid of allow_any_instance_of is to just pass additional header as an option in `get`, `post` etc. methods.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your answer. So, because you're stating that I cannot create local variable in one block and expect to exists in another block. Can you tell what another block you're saying ( is it the describe or the context or the other before block ) ? as I know the `one block` you mention is the first before block, right? I'm so sorry for being newbie in testing. I just want to know what's happening. Thanks

Comment: One thing also, why it worked in my another spec that I refactored using the new method which has the same structure. :thinking:

Comment: @PepengA. I meant before block and then context block.