# Modify rails session data for rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing rspecs for my ruby on rails application, and I'm using google for my authentication. I had my specs all setup fine before I added auth, but now I need some way to test an authenticated user. Here is what one of my specs looks like.

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Test', type: :request do
  it 'should return 200' do
    get '/test'
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
  end
end
```

This is failing with a 401 as it rightfully should be.

I need to add the authentication information into the session variable so the controller can recognize that the user is logged in, but there doesn't seem to be a way to modify the session variable from rspec. I guess I could make a test google account and setup some helpers that would log me into a real google account, but it seems like there should be a better way to write tests. I've seen a couple of examples online, but most seem to be for older versions of rails.

I'm on Rails 7.0.4.3 and ruby 3.2.2

Edit:
It occurs to me that I should probably include my auth code.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_auth

  private

  def require_auth
    user_id = session[:user_id]

    if !user_id.present?
      head :unauthorized
    else
      @auth_user = User.find(user_id)

      if !@auth_user.present?
        head :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What gem are you using for Google auth? You can stub that response. E.g. Devise sets `current_user`

Comment: I'm using `googleauth` in my callback to ensure the JWT that gets forwarded is valid and then I set the user_id in the session to id from the user table. I'm not using devise as I couldn't get it to work and it seemed to add a lot of features that I didn't need like email confirmation , password resets, and stuff.

Comment: If you're doing your own thing, even easier: stub this process: "set the user_id in the session to id from the user table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way of easily modifying session variables in the test setup for RSpec request specs unless you add the `rack_session_access` gem or a similar solution.

One approach is to just mock the `auth_user` object in the tests that require a logged in user.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_auth

  private

  def auth_user
    @auth_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def require_auth
    head(:unauthorized) unless auth_user.present?
  end
end

# spec/support/test_macros.rb
module TestMacros
  def log_in(user)
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:auth_user).and_return(user)
  end
end

# spec/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(TestMacros)
end

it 'should return 200' do
  user = # create or fabricate user
  log_in(user)
  get '/test'
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
end
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315529/allow-any-instance-of-and-allow-using-the-instance-double-is-not-working-properl) as to `allow_any_instance_of` isn't encouraged to be used

Answer (score 0):

As `allow_any_instance_of` has been discouraged, I have opted for an alternative approach by using a partial double to override a session.

Note: To apply this approach to the your(questioner's) code, you need to have `before_hook_for_test` called before `require_auth`.

#### 1. Create a concern as shown below.

```rb
module HookableForTest
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def before_hook_for_test
    self.class.before_hook_for_test(self)
  end

  included do
    before_action :before_hook_for_test
  end

  class_methods do
    def before_hook_for_test(controller)
      # mocked in test
    end
  end
end
```

#### 2. Include the concern in your subject controller.

```rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
  include HookableForTest
  # ...
end
```

#### 3. Stub the `before_hook_for_test` class method in the test before making the request.

```rb
before do
    expect(YourController).to receive(:before_hook_for_test) do |controller|
        controller.session[:user_id] = 123
    end
end
```